# VBA (Excel) ActiveX ListBox Change Event recursive behaviour

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm not a VBA programmer so I apologize in advance if some of my terminology in this question is incorrect. A colleague of mine wanted to clear the selection from a list box as soon as it was selected. After some googling we found one way to do it was via the Change event. Initially we tried:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

However, it seemed that setting the **Selected** property to False triggers a **Change** event on the list box and this effectively becomes an infinite loop and causes Excel (2007) to crash. Given we knew there were two entries we also tried:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    ListBox1.Selected(0) = False
    ListBox1.Selected(1) = False
End Sub
```

And that works! Though we'd expect the same behaviour - for the setting of the **Selected** property to cause the Change event to trigger again and to get an infinite loop.

However it seems that once e.g. **ListBox1.Selected(0) = False** the Change event is re-triggered but in that iteration it doesn't retrigger on this line - i guess because it knows that this **Selected** property has already been set to to **False** for this item, so nothing is changing.

But if that is the case then we'd also expect that behaviour in the **first** solution .. so it seems there is some difference in saying **ListBox1.Selected(i) = False** versus specifying the actual item index directly (rather than via the variable **i**).

Does anyone know the reason for this behaviour? Hope the question makes sense i've tried to explain it as best I can.

Thanks
  Amit

Comment: To stop re-triggering events read [this](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/NoEvents00.asp).

Comment: Thanks Cool Blue - in fact we did resolve the looping issue using something similar to what's discussed in the link you posted .. but my question above (probably not very clear!) is to try to understand why the behaviour differs in the two cases (the first gives an infinite loop the second does not)

Comment: Are there literally only 2 items available to select in the listbox? Or do you mean that only 2 items have been selected?

Comment: For the purpose of the example there were two items in the list box, but for the actual use case there are 5

Comment: I can't reproduce any difference between the two versions (Excel 2007). The Change Event is raised only for Item which is selected [Selected(Item_Index) equals to True], but when Change Event handler is Re-Entered, then this Item is de-selected [Selected(Item_Index) equals to False] which is correct and Change Event is not Re-Entered again. So it works as expected and is for both versions the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a year late to the party but I hope this will help others. I was having problem with **Listbox1_Click()** infinite loop rather than **change()**. However, I think this can be a viable solution to both.

Whenever I called **Listbox1.Selected(i) = True**, it would trigger it as a **Click()** or a **Change()**. In my **click()** routine, there are certain index that will cause the entire list to repopulate itself with a new list and **reselect** itself. This causes the infinite loop when it reselected itself. It took me a day to troubleshoot, but in the end the solution was not to use **click()** event; instead, I used **MouseDown()** event with a little calculation. This eliminate the use of **click()**. Noted that I'm using this in a single select listbox and not a multi select listbox. You can use an **If** statement with a boolean to apply it to multiselect. Goodluck!

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As 

Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    On Error Resume Next  'You can comment this out for trouble shooting
    If Button = 1 And UBound(ListBox1.List) <> -1 Then
        ListBox1.Selected(((Y / 9.75) - 0.5) + ListBox1.TopIndex) = True
        MsgBox "left Click"
        'You can use Button = 2 for right click
        'Do some other stuff including listbox1.select(1234)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I believed this wouldn't add value, but it can be leveraged because the selection is already registered prior to the event firing. Therefore you can detect a change to a specific list item in some cases. For instance, I wanted a list item (0) to 'Reset Filters' below it, it can work in this case because I always clear it. If it's selected, then I know user just did it and I can follow suit.

Answer (score 0):

Attach your loop to the click event instead of the change event to stop the infinite loops:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
'Do the stuff you want to do based on the selection

'Clear selections
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
Next i
End Sub
```

I do not believe the "why" of this question has an easy answer. Generally, word is very linear and can only process 1 thing at a time. Modern processors however, optimize code and run things in tandem. Word simply gets confused in predictable enough ways to provide relatively consistent workarounds for the confusion. The trick you mentioned above (doing it twice) is one popular way to handle this issue (I saw many reccomendations back when I had the same issue with list boxes).

I prefer to enhance the logic rather then attempt a sloppy work around. As above, rather then turn off events or use the double trick, I simply realized that the change event was not the correct event to use.

Comment: I believe we did try with ListBox Click but i think that this triggered before the selection was "physically" selected in the list box, so changing the Selected property had no effect

Answer (score 0):

I would have to do more research on this, but I do know that during a `For...Next` loop, once the code hits the `Next` line it adds 1 to the variable (assuming you haven't defined a `Step`) and then runs a logic test to determine if the variable is still between your inclusive `For blah` conditions.  Because each of these runs independently, it allows the code to check for your `_Change()` event.  Some great workarounds for preventing an infinite loop: [Change() Event Infinite Loops](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=110:worksheet-change-event-excel-vba&catid=79&Itemid=475)

**EDIT:  Here is some additional information on what causes the trigger [ListBox.Change Documentation](http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/ListBox.Change).  It mentions that**

> Also, a programmatic change to ListBox.ListIndex also triggers the Change event.

**which might be what is being checked between loops.**

Answer (score 0):

You are right about using the Change event, but it's somehow tricky in ListBoxes. You're obviously triggering the Change event every time you deselect an element, because you are *changing* the ListBox from code.

The answer from *guitarthrower* goes in the good direction, but I don't think that `Application.EnableEvents` would do the job in this case as it does not have any effect on ActiveX objects.

So, I would try this two alternatives which try to emulate the job of `Application.EnableEvents` by plain programming:

- Alternative 1: general solution for the Change event. However, it's a bit risky if the `NoExecute` variable is not reseted by any reason (function exiting due to an error).

  ```
  Private NoExecute As Boolean

  Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

      If NoExecute Then Exit Sub

      NoExecute = True

      For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
          ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
      Next

      NoExecute = False

  End Sub
  ```
- Alternative 2: best solution in this case, although not as pretty as the previous one.

  ```
  Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
      For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
          If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
              ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
          End If
      Next
  End Sub
  ```

Let me know wether it worked.

This site describes Alternative 1 in depth: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm

Comment: Thanks for the info - in fact we did implement the first solution as a work around, my question was more why is there a difference in behaviour for the two cases I described

Answer (score 0):

To stop the infinite insanity, you can do this (tough even better question is, why would you do this anyway, because after this no value can be selected or actually can be, but it's immediately changed back to false) -

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1 
         if ListBox1.Selected(i) = true then ListBox1.Selected(i) = false 
    Next i
End Sub
```

Now the reason for the infinite loop is not visible and one can only guess, but first lets correct the assumption that the code block without the for next loop would not cause the same issue. It actually does the same thing as the first one and get stuck in an infinite loop, if you change the value of the ListBox1.Selected(1) or later..

Why this happens is the change event will be triggered right after the first value is changed, and as the first cell is changed the change event gets triggered and code execution is stopped for that instance and begins again. Now both of the codes work without causing a loop if only the first item is changed and why this happens is probably for the compiler kicks in with it's automatics. I can't tell you the real reason behind the happenings, but what probably happens is the compiler predicts when only the first value is changed and optimizes the code to do only the one change and nothing else and when other values change it is trying to rewrite every value and the first value every time and again the infinite loop is triggered.

That's just how it is, to get a full understand what is happening under the hood, you'd better contact MS.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference: If you just want to **disable selection** in a `ListBox` control you can either use

```vb
ListBox.Enabled = False
```

or

```vb
ListBox.Locked = True
```

or both, of course.

You can find details on the difference in behaviour on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278538%28v=office.15%29.aspx).
Basically it's supposed to be like this (directly from the linked MSDN article above):

- If `Enabled` and `Locked` are both **True**, the control can receive focus and appears normally (not dimmed) in the form. The user can copy, but not edit, data in the control.
- If `Enabled` is **True** and `Locked` is **False**, the control can receive focus and appears normally in the form. The user can copy and edit data in the control.
- If `Enabled` is **False** and `Locked` is **True**, the control cannot receive focus and is dimmed in the form. The user can neither copy nor edit data in the control.
- If `Enabled` and `Locked` are both **False**, the control cannot receive focus and is dimmed in the form. The user can neither copy nor edit data in the control.

Note that I'm not sure about the behaviour in Office 2007 since I tried your example with Office 2013 and get the exact same behaviour for both code snippets. And they both **don't** prevent the selection but rather do "nothing" (well, they get called two times but the change doesn't affect the displayed selection).

And during my experiments I also noticed, that the `ListBox_Change` event gets called before the `ListBox_Click` event.