# Change text-box when selection is made in list-box

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user-form with 2 List-boxes and two corresponding Text-boxes. When I make a selection in a list-box, I want its corresponding text-box to update to have that same value. I have arranged functions like this to accomplish it within my user-form:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    TextBox1.Value = TopSelectedValue(ListBox1)
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_Click()
    TextBox2.Value = TopSelectedValue(ListBox2)
End Sub

Function TopSelectedValue(myBox As MSForms.ListBox) As String
    'Finds value of first selected item in ListBox
    Select Case myBox.MultiSelect
        Case fmMultiSelectSingle
            TopSelectedValue = myBox.Value
        Case fmMultiSelectMulti, fmMultiSelectExtended
            TopSelectedValue = myBox.List(TopSelectedIndex(myBox))
    End Select
End Function

Function TopSelectedIndex(myBox As MSForms.ListBox) As Integer  
    Dim k As Integer
    Select Case myBox.MultiSelect                        
        Case fmMultiSelectSingle                         
            TopSelectedIndex = myBox.ListIndex           
        Case fmMultiSelectMulti, fmMultiSelectExtended   
            For k = 0 To myBox.ListCount - 1             
                If myBox.Selected(k) = True Then         
                    TopSelectedIndex = k                 
                    Exit Function                        
                End If
            Next k
            TopSelectedIndex = -1                        
    End Select
End Function
```

Note: `ListBox1` is single select, `ListBox2` is multi-select.

The problem is, everything works perfectly fine for `ListBox1` (`TextBox1` updates on cue when `ListBox1` changes) but nothing happens to `TextBox2` when `ListBox2` is selected or changes.

I tried to fix it by adding this type of code to somehow reset the selections, but this also failed to help:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    TextBox1.Value = TopSelectedValue(ListBox1)
    Dim C As MSForms.Control
    For Each C In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf C Is MSForms.ListBox Then C.ListIndex = -1
    Next C
End Sub
```

Why aren't both list-box/text-box relationships behaving the same way, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: It is supposed to take the first selection in the list. You can see above the functions `TopSelectedIndex` and `TopSelectedValue` which accomplish this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128088/vba-excel-activex-listbox-change-event-recursive-behaviour - it must be related to this. If you step through it, it works.

Comment: @Raystafarian looks like _Change event works fine. Thanks for that! I wonder why _Click doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure, it must a weird event handler thing - I wonder if it happens to non Active-x controls